# Parse and store nested array with RestKit

Tags: json, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've iOS project which is using RestKit 0.21.0 component responsible to get, parse and store in Core Data responses from remote server. In one of the backend JSON response I have something like that:

```
"response": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "start_time": "10:00:00",
  "end_time": "14:00:00",
  "name": "Object name",
  "occurrences": [
    "2013-09-13T14:00:00",
    "2013-09-20T14:00:00",
    "2013-09-27T14:00:00"
  ]
},
.
.
.
]
```

Generally I'm able to parse and store in Core Data received objects. I've only problem with nested array *occurrences*.

Do you have any advices how should I properly parse and store this collection?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to map it to dates. To do that you generally need a container. You can also simply map to an array of strings and post-process.

1) Array of strings:

Just add an `NSArray` property to your destination object and map `occurrences` to it. This would be a transformable attribute in Core Data (could be transient). Now you can iterate the array and create the dates (could be done in `willSave`).

2) Relationship to dates:

Create a new entity, call it `Occurrence`. It has a single date property. Use a 'nil' keypath mapping to create instances of this `Occurrence` entity and map each of the dates to a new instance (the conversion to `NSDate` will be done for you). You have no identity so your only option would be to use the date as the unique identifier.